# Edit Comment link breaks when I edit a comment and then press [enter] to save

Tags: bug, status-norepro, internet-explorer, comment-edits

Confirmed in IE9 (latest version).  When I press the `<enter>` key after editing comment, clicking on the comment's edit link again does nothing.* I have to refresh the page to get the edit link to work again.  Only affects the currently-edited comment, not other comments on the page.

The problem does not occur if I use the mouse to save the comment.

*<sub>Yes, I do in fact edit comments twice, often enough to make this inconvenient.</sub>

Comment: Hm... strange. My advice for now is, don't use IE9.

Comment: What the...A quick inspection suggests the problem might be that IE 9 gets upset that the focused textarea was stolen from it, and focuses on some sort of text node in the `tbody` instead...preventing clicks from triggering on the edit link for reasons unknown. Blurring the textarea before removing it appears to fix it, although that might be circumstantial. Pressing tab or clicking some other selectable content after submitting the edit the first time seems to correct the situation, as a temporary workaround.

Comment: as always, @TimStone is on the pounce before anyone else. Wonder if he's way too bored :P

Comment: Just ran across this myself. Incredibly annoying, and I agree with the original author that I make edits twice (or more), so it does come into play.. and "make this inconvenient".

Comment: This problem also exists in IE 10 on Windows 8

Comment: I was just about to post this as a bug report for IE11! Shouldn't something like that be fixed by now...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. I am unable to reproduce this issue in the current build of our sites. If it remains an issue, please let me know!

Comment: It hasn't happened in awhile, and I'm no longer using IE9, so I'm going to mark this as resolved
.