# Editing comments steals my mouse!

Tags: bug, comments

IE 10.0.9200.16660
Windows 8

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open Internet Explorer
2. Navigate to http://serverfault.com (and possibly any other SE site)
3. Create a comment
4. Edit that comment
5. Finalize the edit by using the Enter/Return key. Do *not* click the "Save Edit" button.

This causes the focus to be "trapped" in some way and mouse functions, including scroll wheel, do not work until the page is refreshed. When this happens, a blinking cursor appears after the edit link, as pictured below.

[image: comment example]

Comment: Your mice are so tasty though, why would we ever want to let go?

Comment: Upvoted because of the sad face.  EDIT: For the record, I just edited this and hit the <Enter> key, and nothing happened.  I had to click the Save Edits button.  IE 8 on Win2K.

Comment: Can't resist a freehand sad face.

Comment: Chrome on OSX 10.8.4 doesn't seem to have this issue

Comment: @StephenTG Right, I tried this in multiple browsers and it only seems to happen in IE, which is why I listed it at the top of the bug report. I'll add an additional step.

Comment: @MDMarra Ok, wasn't sure if you'd checked others. Just thought I'd see about Chrome on mac.

Comment: Sounds somewhat similar to this issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120221/edit-comment-link-breaks-when-i-edit-a-comment-and-then-press-enter-to-save

Comment: @JohnnyBones liar! You can't install IE8 on W2k!

Comment: @MDMarra - Sorry. XP. Professional, to be exact.  I'm on my work computer. I actually run Firefox on my home computer, which is Win2K. Haven't tested that one yet.